# Regex for parsing with newline character

Tags: regex, string, perl

I am trying to debug a perl script to parse of a `snmpwalk` output  on a table containing a IPv6  address with Port details.

The `snmpwalk` command execution and result on shell is as follows:

```
[root@newton log]# /usr/bin/snmpwalk -v 2c -c secret localhost  SNMP-TARGET-MIB::snmpTargetAddrTAddress
SNMP-TARGET-MIB::snmpTargetAddrTAddress.'2' = Hex-STRING: FD 22 1A 16 0E D3 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 10 00 41 
00 A2
```

The perl script tries to get the value after `snmpTargetAddrTAddress.` -> that is 2 and then tries to get value after `Hex-STRING`. It uses the following regular expression in code

```
@buf   = `$snmpwalk $address_oid`;
foreach (@buf) {
      if (/snmpTargetAddrTAddress\.'(.+?)' = Hex-STRING: ([\w ]+)/)
             my $name = $1;
             my $rest= $2;
             log_msg( LOG_CRIT, "Found IP $rest for $name" );
      }
```

$1 is equal to `2`

$2 is equal to `FD 22 1A 16 0E D3 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 10 00 41`

But I need the value `00 A2` that appears in newline in shell as well.

I tried the online tool - https://regex101.com/. It provided the regex as ([\w ]+)(\n[\w ]+). But in using in the code, I don't get any output.

The following does not output any

`if (/snmpTargetAddrTAddress\.'(.+?)' = Hex-STRING: ([\w ]+)(\n[\w ]+)/`

What could I be doing wrong? The expression above in the online tool, yields the results. What other regex can I use if I need to get the characters appearing in newline in the shell output?

Code after @GMB suggestion:

```
if(/snmpTargetAddrTAddress\.'(.+?)' = Hex-STRING: ([\w\s\n]+)/) {
        my $name = $1;
        my $rest = $2;
        log_msg( LOG_CRIT, "Found IP $rest for $name" );
 }
```

The log seen is :
`" Found IP FD 22 1A 16 0E D3 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 10 00 41  for 2"`

**Update:** Based on the comments from @zdim & @ikegami, I was wrong in assuming that "00 A2" would be part of the second iteration itself. Since they appear in third line, they are seen in the third iteration of the `foreach`

Comment: It'd be very helpful to show how you get this string ... do you run the command under backticks by any chance (and assign to a scalar)?  (Do those `00 A2` really come on a separate line with this command?)

Comment: Re the update, You're matching against `$_`. Does it actually contain the entire text or just the first line?

Comment: conf_params.trap_target_ip6

@zdim, ikegami. My bad . In not checking $_. That seems not to contain the entire text. I have updated the code in description. I am using `foreach` after running the command.The "00 A2" is seen in the third iteration of the loop!.

Comment: Alright, that is better.  So, what is in `@buff`, can you show that?  What "_third iteration_" -- the sample from running that in the shell, shown at the beginning of the question, shows two lines altogether?

Comment: If the wanted "_rest_" is indeed all the rest from the output, then you can assign to a scalar (`my $ret = qx(...);`), in which case backticks returns a multiline string, and then use GMB's answer on that.  (Or join lines `my $ret = join '', @buff;` and use it on that.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not simply add the new line character to the list of allowed characters? Actually, as commented by [zdim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4653379/zdim), `\s` matches both the space and the new line characters, so you could just do:

```
/snmpTargetAddrTAddress\.'(.+?)' = Hex-STRING: ([\w\s]+)/
```

If needed, you can then remove it  from the parsed value:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = qq/SNMP-TARGET-MIB::snmpTargetAddrTAddress.'2' = Hex-STRING: FD 22 1A 16 0E D3 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 10 00 41\n00 A2/;
if (my ($addr, $hex) =  ($str =~ /snmpTargetAddrTAddress\.'(.+?)' = Hex-STRING: ([\w\s]+)/)) {
    $hex =~  s/\n/ /; 
    print "addr: $addr\nhex: $hex\n"
}
```

Yields:

```
addr: 2
hex: FD 22 1A 16 0E D3 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 10 00 41 00 A2
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried your solution. Somehow, my code ins't giving the result. I have posted more of my code in my question .

Comment: I suppose, I need to remove newline char and then print it in `log_msg`?

Comment: @Prabhu  There was a typo (space missing before `=` in the regex), which I just fixed -- try again.  (I also added a space instead of `\n`, which was previously merely removed)

Comment: @zdim: thanks for fixing my typos (I mixed things up while copying from my terminal...)! And thanks for the hint on `\n` vs `\s` - I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Try `Hex-STRING:\s+([a-fA-F0-9]{2}(?:\s*[a-fA-F0-9]{2})*)`
for that part

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/dWLBLO/1)